# Looking for simple way to build Linq dynamic / conditional expression

Tags: c#, linq

Given tables as:

**Table1**

- id
- stringfield1
- stringfield2
- stringfield3
- stringfield4

**Table2**

- id
- table1_id
- stringfield1
- datefield1

Given a **UI** allow user to make fency query on:

- dropdwonlist1 with *any* and *table1.stringfield1* values
- dropdwonlist2 with *any* and *table1.stringfield2* values
- dropdwonlist3 with *any* and *table1.stringfield3* values
- dropdwonlist4 with *any* and *table1.stringfield4* values
- dropdwonlist5 with *any* and *table2.stringfield1* values
- dropdwonlist6 with [*any, the, before, after, between*]
- calendar1 to link with *table2.datefield1*
- calendar2 to link with *table2.datefield1*

And as result datagridview with everyfields.

I want to build conditional query as *if not "any" add this condition*.

Considering that, simple LINQ query is not applicable:

```
Table2
  .Where(x => x.stringfield1 == dropdwonlist1.SelectedValue)
  .Where(x => x.stringfield2 == dropdwonlist2.SelectedValue)
  .Where(x => x.stringfield3 == dropdwonlist3.SelectedValue)
(...)
```

There is [Expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397951.aspx) in documentation but that looks too much.

Is there simplest way to build my dynamic query ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expression trees look scarier than they are, but you are right, in your situation they are unnecessary: you could use a static condition that is smart enough to ignore dropdowns that have no selection. You can do it like this:

```
Table2
.Where(x => dropdwonlist1.SelectedValue == null || x.stringfield1 == dropdwonlist1.SelectedValue)
.Where(x => dropdwonlist2.SelectedValue == null || x.stringfield2 == dropdwonlist2.SelectedValue)
.Where(x => dropdwonlist3.SelectedValue == null || x.stringfield3 == dropdwonlist3.SelectedValue)
```

Comment: clever for what I need.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) for similar scenarios with great success.

Specifically, you should be able to use the [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to accomplish what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's common to forget that you can keep building up LINQ expressions across multiple statements. It's one of the great niceties of LINQ. I would simplify dasblinkenlight's answer for the LINQ-to-SQL translation that's going to happen afterward to:

```
IQueryable<T> query = Table2;

if (dropdownlist1.SelectedValue == null)
    query = query.Where(x => x.stringfield1 == dropdownlist1.SelectedValue);
// etc
```

That way anything with a null value doesn't get mixed up into the where clauses at all, reducing the chances the generated SQL has unnecessary conditions in it.

I like Donut's answer best as a more generalized solution though - for example LINQKit would let you write a loop over the 6 dropdowns that writes each where clause if necessary.